# Sql update query in eclipse

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, sql-update

My question is about the Update query shown in eclipse using MySQL, received from the code below

This is my database:
  [image]
I'm trying to do on eclipse the next update query but I'm having trouble

```
 public static void update_Payment(String month,int number) {
    String sqlupdate = "UPDATE tenant SET month=?  WHERE appartmentnum =? ";

    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement(sqlupdate);
        pst.setInt(1, 4);
        pst.setInt(2, 1);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException var2) {
        var2.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I know that I don't have column name month in my database, I just want to receive from the user the name of the month for example

this is working fine 
when I change [the column name from ] `month` to `april` or `jan`

thx for help

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: You must specify a valid column name

Comment: Are you asking how to generate your query dynamically?

Comment: @JacobBarnes theres no way to get string from user ? and using it as column?

Comment: I think what you are asking is to do something like this:

    String sqlupdate = "UPDATE tenant SET " + month + " =? WHERE appartmentnum =?";

Comment: are you trying to do this? "UPDATE tenant SET " + month + "  = ?  WHERE appartmentnum =?

Comment: @isaace exectly

Comment: ok, is it working now?

Comment: @JacobBarnes I agree, the design is bad.

Comment: Also please look how `July` is spelled as your column name.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are building this SQL statement as a string, please try the following:

```
 public static void update_Payment(String month,int number) {
    String sqlupdate = "UPDATE tenant SET " + month + "=? WHERE appartmentnum =? ";

    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement(sqlupdate);
        pst.setInt(1, 4);
        pst.setInt(2, 1);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException var2) {
        var2.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

You still have a problem:

You need a way to pass in the appropriate value for `?`. There isn't a default way of converting month to month number. You can write a solution to that in code or db, e.g. [Get month number from month name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355504/get-month-number-from-month-name)

Or of course just add another parameter and pass in the appropriate integer representing the month similar to what you're doing for apt#

Comment: @HaiVaknin Awesome, glad I could help! Will you please accept my response as an answer?

Comment: jacob i have another question that iam stuck on

Comment: @HaiVaknin, sure, what's up?

Comment: on the same database i need to sum the monthly payment for each month For example, in January everyone paid But in May not everyone paid because there the value 0  i need to return the amount of each moth could you help me?

Comment: I'll add an example solution to my answer, but this database schema could be much improved to make queries like that easier.

Comment: that's giving me only January sum

Comment: Ya, sorry, just rethought that and obviously that would only give Jan.